# Editing multiple text sections

Tags: interface, text-editor

I have three text sections where the first is available to all, the second is available to a group, and the third is available to a subgroup.

The back-end user needs to be able to edit each, and understands that each section represents something different.  A front-end user, however, will see each of the three as one continuous text block, and should not know that there are three sections, and should think there is only one.

How should the back-end user be able to edit (or add to if initially empty) the three text sections?  Should the three sections take up screen space on the back-end if they are initially empty?  How should the back-end user know that the first is for all, second for group, and third for sub-group?

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fopxSV.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final text may be read as a whole by the subgroup users; this should be clearly understandable. Therefore, I would display a the final resulting text in continuity. Preferably you could use inline editing, but you can also use three textareas next to the end-result.

Check this:

[image]

Of course, you should use a proper label for blocks 1,2,3.

Also, if you have several kinds of groups and subgroups, this solution would have to be updated to allow choices between alternative texts.

Comment: Your solution uses a bit of real estate, but do like it.  If a block was initially empty, how should it work?

Comment: With an empty block, you can just use placeholders (with a lighter color).
 You can figure many solutions to save space (I don't know how is the rest of your wireframe). For instance, you can replace the help-labels by help-icons, or just remove them and add a contextual help when editing.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the back end should have three separated sections to edit, with correct labeling for each one.

Something like this:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fY2CzG.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Should the textarea be open, or should there be an edit/add call to action next to each?  Inline editing? One or 3 save buttons?  Should each take up the same amount of space regardless of content?   PS.  I meant to add requirements to letting user know which one was all/group/etc, but you did so in your answer :)